# discord.js v12 Discord.EvaluatedPermissions :((

Tags: discord.js

uptill now when i was in v11.x.x i was using

my dashboard.js looks like this

```
 const perms = Discord.EvaluatedPermissions;
    renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", {perms});
```

but now perms is undefined when i updated bot to discord.js v12 and they said evaluatedPermissions has been removed entirely, see the Permissions page

what can i do to replace Discord.EvaluatedPermissions to get perms

so i can use it in my dashboard.ejs file

```
  user.guilds.forEach(guild => { 
    const permsOnGuild = new perms(guild.permissions);
    if(!permsOnGuild.has("MANAGE_GUILD")) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Discord.Permissions` instead of `EvaluatedPermissions`

```
const perms = Discord.Permissions
 renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", {perms});
```